# Can't login to my own login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've created my own login page but when i try to sign in by clicking the submit button it jumps right to the "catch" where it returns View() instead of redirecting to Admin. I can't seem to find any information about it by googling it. I have also tried to remove try and catch and got this exception: "InvalidOprationException was unhanded by user code" Sequence contains no elements.

Here's my login method:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
            public static byte[] lagHash(string innString)
    {
        var algoritm = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] data, utdata;
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(innString);
        utdata = algoritm.ComputeHash(data);
        return utdata;
    }

public ActionResult Login()
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection innAdmin)
    {
        string Username = innAdmin["Username"];

        try
        {
            byte[] passwordArray;
            passwordArray = createHash(innAdmin["Password"]);

            var db = new Models.DataClass1DataContext();
            var Admin = (from s in db.Admins
                         where s.Username == Username &&
                         s.Password == passwordArray
                         select s).Single();
            if (Admin.Username == innAdmin["Username"])
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception wrong)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the aspx file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username :</td>
        <td>
            <input type = "text" name="Username" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password :</td>
        <td>
            <input type = "password" name="Password" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type = "submit" value="Log In" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't do anything"? Is it not entering the method you have shown above? Throws exception? More details please....

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Yes is not entering the method, It jumps right to Catch where it returns the view.

Comment: @SLaks sorry, i have already created the Hash file and it seems like the hash is not the problem.

Comment: **What exception do you get**?

Comment: _For security reasons_, you should salt your hash.  (it won't solve your problem)

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice, but if i understood right, the exception i get is from the Catch where i am being returned to the View() which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid… Do you mean exception from the catch? If so it means that is wrong and i cannot log in.

Comment: remove the try/catch. You should then get the YSOD with the error details. If you do not get YSOD let me know.

Comment: @santiagoIT I removed the try and catch as u said, and when i pressed the submit button i got this message in Visual Studio: "InvalidOperationException was unhanded by user code" Sequence contains no elements

Comment: Despite the valiant efforts to solve this problem, I'm voting to close as Too Localized. Unless the original question can be edited to reflect anything like what the actual problem seems to be, it isn't going to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`It seems that you need to convert your byte array to a string. Use the proper enconding and convert to a string.

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes, EncodingType encodingType) 
{ 
    System.Text.Encoding encoding=null; 
    switch (encodingType) 
    { 
        case EncodingType.ASCII: 
            encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
            break;    
        case EncodingType.Unicode: 
            encoding=new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding(); 
            break;    
        case EncodingType.UTF7: 
            encoding=new System.Text.UTF7Encoding(); 
            break;    
        case EncodingType.UTF8: 
            encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
            break;    
    } 
    return encoding.GetString(bytes); 
}
```

*** EDIT ***
try the following:

```
var admin = (from s in db.Admins where s.Username == Username && s.Password == passwordArray select s).SingleOrDefault();
if (admin != null)
{
return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Admin");
}
else
{
return View();
}
```

*** EDIT 2 ***
That means your validation is failing.
Try this:

```
var test = (from s in db.Admins where s.Username == Username select s).SingleOrDefault();
if (test != null)
{
   var test2 = test.Password;
}
```

place a breakpoint and examine the test object. It should not be null.
Look at the retrieved password and compare it against the hashed one you are using.
You are closing in now.

** EDIT 3 **
Well, then that means the problem is with your datastore. The username you are using to login just does not exist, therefore login can never succeed!

Comment: I've tried the following code and it did not work either. When i pressed the submit button it just returning the View();

Comment: hmm thats odd! i've double checked my username and password + nearly created a new one just to try to see if I'm using wrong password or username, but it seems neither both are the problems :S Man.. this is frustrating!

Comment: Can you connect to the membership provider manually and double check? (from VS Menu Project->ASP.NET Configuration)
Make sure that the your entity framework is properly configured. Maybe you are pointing at a different database all together.

Comment: I got this message when i'm testing the provider: Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider. U got some ideas?